# Haunt 42 - How does the traitor attack the [spoiler]?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

The rules don't seem to say what are defense traits for the

> statue

and they don't seem to say what the traitor attacks with?

Answer (score 2):

The Traitor's tome intentionally doesn't cover the [spoiler]

That's up for the Heroes to let the traitor know. The Secret's of survival book has all the rules for

> attacking the statue.

Here's the relevant bits from the Secrets of Survival book:

> Once the Statue animates, it remains in whatever state it transformed into for the rest of the game. When the Statue has been animated, **tell the traitor what form it has taken**. 
>  If the traitor attacks the Statue and defeats it, **it isn’t stunned**. Instead, the Statue **can’t lower an ability during its next turn**. The Statue **can still be moved** to follow the traitor.

So this is how it works:

> The traitor **can attack the Statue normally**, and the heroes should let the traitor know so when it animates. The traitor attacks with the default might, and the statue defends with might, as normal in any combat - unless an item says differently (like The Ring allows you to attack with Sanity). The Statue's attributes are 8 for everything (Speed, Might, Sanity and Knowledge) and it defends with the appropriate attribute for the attack.